# why event.which always returns 1 on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to know which mouse button user clicked (if any) it works perfect in Chrome : 1 for left button and 2 for the right in firefox It does not matter if user clicks at all it always returns 1

```
   $('body').on('mousemove',function(e)
    {

        if(e.which==1)
        {

        }
    });
```

any ideas ?

thank you

Comment: You're binding a `mousemove` event, not a click event.

Comment: Is this a drag handler? Just keep track of `e.button` from your `mousedown`.

Comment: This begs the question. Are you testing the same code on different browsers (as you should be if you are checking compatability) or are you writing different code for each browser?

Comment: It seems that Chrome's behaviour is convenient, but non-standard. The mousemove event should not contain information about clicked mousebuttons.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is listening to mousemove, not click events

Answer (score 1):

`e.which` is for Keyboard events.

```
$('body').on('keyup',function(ev){
   console.log(ev.which)
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.which

Comment: The OP is using jQuery, which does also normalize button presses for mouse events. http://api.jquery.com/event.which/